# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable in concatenating different dataframes of certain types

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, typeerror

I keep getting the following error.

[image]

I read a file that contains time series data of 3 columns: [meter ID] [daycode(explain later)] [meter reading in kWh]

```
consum = pd.read_csv("data/File1.txt", delim_whitespace=True, encoding = "utf-8", names =['meter', 'daycode', 'val'], engine='python')
consum.set_index('meter', inplace=True)
test = consum.loc[[1048]]
```

I will observe meter readings for all the length of data that I have in this file, but first filter by meter ID.

```
test['day'] = test['daycode'].astype(str).str[:3]
test['hm'] = test['daycode'].astype(str).str[-2:]
```

For readability, I convert daycode based on its rule. First 3 digits are in range of 1 to 365 x2 = 730, last 2 digits in range of 1 to 48. These are 30-min interval reading of 2-year length. (but not all have in full)

So I create files that contain dates in one, and times in another separately. I will use index to convert the digits of daycode into the corresponding date & time that these file contain.

```
#dcodebook index starts from 0. So minus 1 from the daycode before match
dcodebook = pd.read_csv("data/dcode.txt", encoding = "utf-8", sep = '\r', names =['match'])
#hcodebook starts from 1
hcodebook = pd.read_csv("data/hcode.txt", encoding = "utf-8", sep ='\t', lineterminator='\r', names =['code', 'print'])
hcodebook = hcodebook.drop(['code'], axis= 1)
```

For some weird reason, dcodebook was indexed using `.iloc` function as I understood, but hcodebook needed `.loc`.

```
#iloc: by int-position
#loc: by label value
#ix: by both
day_df = dcodebook.iloc[test['day'].astype(int) - 1].reset_index(drop=True)
#to avoid duplicate index Valueerror, create separate dataframes..
hm_df = hcodebook.loc[test['hm'].astype(int) - 1]
#.to_frame error / do I need .reset_index(drop=True)?
```

The following line is where the code crashes.

```
datcode_df = day_df(['match']) + ' ' + hm_df(['print'])
print datcode_df
print test
```

## What I don't understand:

- **I tested earlier that columns of different dataframes can be merged using the simple addition as seen**
- I initially assigned this to the existing column ['daycode'] in test dataframe, so that previous values will be replaced. And the same error msg was returned.

Please advise.

Comment: You need remove `()` in `datcode_df = day_df(['match']) + ' ' + hm_df(['print'])` to `datcode_df = day_df['match'] + ' ' + hm_df['print']`

Comment: Hard without data, but what about `hm_df = hcodebook.loc[test['hm'].astype(int) - 1].reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: But also need same szie of both DataFrames, so is necessary `day` and `hm` are unique.

Comment: Yep that seems to be precisely the issue, you're awesome.

Comment: One small notice, please check print datcode_df.tail() if correct join - if in one column or more are `NaN`s it means filtering return different sized DataFrames.

Comment: There is no way since [day] [hm] are split from the same column! But double-checked as well! thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need same size of both `DataFrames`, so is necessary `day` and `hm` are `unique`.

Then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for same indices and last remove `()` in join:

```
day_df = dcodebook.iloc[test['day'].astype(int) - 1].reset_index(drop=True)
hm_df = hcodebook.loc[test['hm'].astype(int) - 1].reset_index(drop=True)

datcode_df = day_df['match'] + ' ' + hm_df['print']
```